# Error with levene_test() from rstatix: problem with mutate() and filter()

Tags: r, rstatix

When I try to execute the `levene_test()` function, something that I previously did without problems, I get the following error:

```
 noc01_long %>%

group_by(block) %>%
levene_test(brady ~ group)

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `data`.
x Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Column `term` not found in `.data`
i Input `..1` is `.data$term != ""`.
i Input `data` is `map(.data$data, .f, ...)`.
```

I have tried changing the terms in the formula, as well as calling `library(stats)`, but I have no clue what might be happening. Could anyone help?

Comment: try using: leveneTest(brady ~ group, data)

Comment: with library(car)

Answer (score 1):

Tom, try 2 things and see if they help:

1. Update `rstatix`.
2. Unmask the functions that yield the error:

   library(rstatix)

   unloadNamespace('filter') #to prevent rstatix 'filter'

   library(rstatix)

The libraries that mask the function should be called before this statement.